# Subscribing to pubsub concurrently results fatal error: concurrent map writes

Tags: go, http, httpclient, publish-subscribe

While subscribing to GCP pubsub in Go with following setting

```
sub.ReceiveSettings.Synchronous = false
sub.ReceiveSettings.NumGoroutines = 10
sub.ReceiveSettings.MaxOutstandingMessages = 100
```

Doing some business processing finally when connecting to http endpoint as follows:

```
t := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).Clone()
t.MaxIdleConns = 120
t.MaxConnsPerHost = 200
t.MaxIdleConnsPerHost = 120
request, _:= http.NewRequest("POST", "EndPoint", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonValue))
request.Header.Set(graphql.Api_Key, graphql.Api_Key_Value)
client := &http.Client{Timeout: time.Second * constants.QUERY_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, Transport: t}
response, _ := client.Do(request)
```

When the flow reaches to point **response, _:= client.Do(request)**, I am getting following Fatal error
"concurrent map writes" and fatal trace, So server pods goes in restart mode.

Comment: Does the fatal trace show which map is written concurrently?

Comment: No, not, thats the problem, but in fatal trace I find this http client endpoint where crash starts from.

Comment: Is it possible to run or build the application with the `-race` flag?

Comment: Our requirement is to process subscription concurrently. with mutex on around the subscription process all work ok.   Please suggest how this option -race will help

Comment: See [Data Race Detector](https://go.dev/doc/articles/race_detector).